# Words to express that my friend pretended like she was me in class

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Today I asked a friend of mine to attend the online class as I had to leave home. She changed her name on Zoom, closed his camera and muted the microphone so she pretended like she was me.

There must be a sentence or words, I believe, to express this situation. Such as; "Today, I asked a friend of mine to attend the class ... me."

Could you please tell me which words express this situation best? Language to language translators namely Google Translate didn't help.

Comment: 'Attend the class **as** me' would work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your sentence can be completed with a single word, **as**:

> Today, I asked a friend of mine to attend the class as me

Alternatively you can reword the sentence a little and use a more descriptive verb like **impersonate**:

> Today, I asked a friend of mine to impersonate me in class

[Impersonation](https://libguides.library.vcsu.edu/c.php?g=32881&p=208292#s-lg-box-581470) is what it's called in academic honesty policies.

Answer (score 5):

Pretending to be someone else is called *[impersonation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impersonate)*:

- I asked my friend to *impersonate* me on a zoom call so I wouldn't be marked absent.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to use this exact wording, I would use the term "posing", i.e

> Today, I asked a friend of mine to attend the class posing as me

This makes it clear that they are pretending to be you, and keeps the structure the same as your initial sentence. It's also slightly less formal than impersonation, which can imply a more serious level of fraudulence than may otherwise be intended.

Answer (score -1):

another word, an informal one, that is generally used, is 'proxy' - so, you can also use 'proxied', or 'proxying' based on what type sentence it is.

Comment: In normal usage, a proxy is a stand-in, sent in your place and empowered to act on your behalf, but not to take on your identity — they don't pretend to _be_ their principal, only to act _for_ them. Is there an informal usage which differs from that?